# Can anybody locate the "AppleScript Resources for Office 2004" by Microsoft

Tags: excel, reference, applescript, user-guide

I'm looking for the (official MS) guide to scripting Excel with Applescript. I found one for [Word](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macexcel/applescript-reference-guide/f35a471d-0ab7-436c-b5d2-ce7b93321a79?msgId=6484284f-af1a-40ab-a92a-b87cd1a513cb&rtAction=1386747031192) from same era but not Excel. Even four MS support staff (three calls) can't find anything for me, in fact they don't even bother looking.

A document called "MicrosoftOfficeforMac2004ResourceKitv2" links to the microsfot.com/mac page and says goto Resources > Developer Center > AppleScript Resources for Office 2004 section. It doesn't exist any more.

Comment: This is not asking for an opinion — it;s asking for the correct resource location. A verifiable, unequivocal answerable question. Which was provided. Not sure how to reword it to comply more fully with the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try, it's what i've been using lately:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/A/7/3A70FB4B-0C6A-43E3-AAB7-AC9166B25632/Excel2004AppleScriptRef.pdf

Comment: Thanks heaps. You know more than their entire business support team on this.

Comment: Ha, points to you for actually calling them first!